# Laravel Eloquent - list of parent from a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I can get the list of Likes that User `1` did on a Media from Store `1`

```
$medias = User::find(1)->likes()->with('media')->whereHas('media', function($q) {
    $q->where('store_id', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

But i need to retrieve the list of medias, so i tried

```php
$medias = User::find(1)->likes()->with('media')->whereHas('media', function($q) {
    $q->where('store_id', '=', 1);
})->get()->media;
```

But then i get

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$media

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}

class Media extends Model
{
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}

class Like extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Media');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work with

```php
$store->medias()->whereHas('likes', function($q) use($user) {
        return $q->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you get media separate for each like. You should use:

```
$likes = User::find(1)->likes()->with('media')->whereHas('media', function($q) {
    $q->where('store_id', '=', 1);
})->get();

foreach ($likes as $like) {
   $media = $like->media;
   // now you can do something with your media
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get only media, you should add to your `User` model the following relationship:

```
public function medias()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Media','App\Like');
}
```

Now to get your media, you should do :

```
$medias = User::find(1)->medias()->where('store_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

Comment: i was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the list of medias directly without having to loop through the likes on php?

Comment: looks like what i am looking for but didn't work. `inner join like on likes.id = medias.like_id`. Should be `inner join likes on likes.media_id = medias.id`